# How to output with a NPM script the OpenApi.json file generated on backend?

Tags: node.js, swagger, openapi

**Context** : nodejs backend (nestjs, should be the same for any other nodejs backend framework).

I want to write the openapi.json file produced for swagger-ui, on the disk with an NPM script, how to do this in an OS-independent way ?

1. Start the backend (in dev env, not an issue)
2. Fetch the openapi.json asset
3. Save it at a specific location

This [loopback question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58394492/loopback-4-generate-openapi-json-on-build) has the same concern, but triggered at build time and loopback-specific. I'd rather keep this a manually triggered process to avoid outputting this file in other circumstances or contexts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17607214/9138818), I adapted it to fit my needs :

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

function download(filename, url) {
  var file = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
  http.get(url, function (response) {
    response.pipe(file);
  });
}

console.log('Downloading opemapi file from');
download('./../web-api/openapi.json', 'http://localhost:3000/api-json');
```

Here is the addition to the package.json file :

```
"scripts": {
    [...]
    "api:fetch": "node fetch-openapi.js",
    [...]
  },
```

My project is TypeScript-based, so Visual Studio Code suggested to get rid of `require` in favor of `import`, but as this script is directly run by node, I sticked to pre-ES6 syntax.